# Point to Point connection behind NAT

Tags: networking, udp, network-protocols, tcp

I made a simple Networking application that is server client that communicate over LAN.

> client

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)         
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 8080               
s.connect(("117.219.195.10", port))
s.send('q\n');
s.send('boo\n\r');
s.close
```

> server

```
import socket               
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)         
host = socket.gethostname()
print host
port = 8080                
s.bind(("", port))       
s.listen(5)                 
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     
   print 'Got connection from', addr
   c.send('Thank you for connecting\r\n')
   c.close()
```

but while server is behind NAT i need to configure the NAT table in router, Can i have a point to point connection without configuring router? Can i embed the information of NAT table (like on which ip to redirect) in the packet itself so that when packet comes form internet to router it knows which ip in the LAN should get it.

Comment: there are some technique like UDP hole punching

Comment: Well then go use that if you know it. This isn't about programming anyway, so off-topic here.

Comment: may be or may be not i wasn't sure that's why there is no programming tags in my question :)

Comment: why not configure the router on the server side?

Comment: for a end user application you don't what to do that app should work out of the box (like skype) and in my application i don't want data to go through any server

Comment: you mean you peers to talk directly to eachother without a server? then that is not client-server, that is p2p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to develop an application that utilizes [NAT Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) techniques such as [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) to create a tunnel between NAT'd devices. Review those topics to find a solution that works for you.

Comment: NAT traversal is particularly difficult with TCP. Typically with client-server you do not need to traverse NAT because the server would have port forwarding setup, though the OP does specify this is not the case, so your answer does answer the unusual question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you do need to configure port forwarding and this usually involves logging on to your router and using it's administration interface. No you cannot embed this info in the packets.

**However you only need to do this on your server** and **you do not need to resort to NAT traversal for client-server comms once port forwarding is setup on your server**, since what the client sends the server will get through to the server (because you set up port forwarding) a reply from the server to client will automatically be forwarded by your client side NAT as it will be aware you have a TCP connection established to the servers' end point. **That is how you can connect to this website from behind NAT!**

Comment: You're assuming that he is making a website and that the server is perminent enough to setup the infrastructure around it. Either way he specifically asked for a solution without needing to configure the router.

Comment: No it could be any TCP server not neccasirly a web server. I found it a strange scenario where the client is more permanent than the server, sometimes one has to read between the lines and see what they are trying to achieve to help best.

Comment: A common scenario for this is video games: Their network implementation is almost always client<->server and they're almost always each behind NAT. Your answer is not incorrect however.

Comment: I happen to be game network programmer, I know, but if the game is using a public server then port forwarding would be setup on the server and punch though is not necessary, only if you use a p2p topology, or the "server" is one of the gamers, which the OP is not, do you need punch through.